# Flow Error for Recipient ID

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, salesforce-flow

I have a flow to create a record for calibrations. It is an email alert/reminder to the user to add details. However I am getting this error message:

Error Occurred: recipientIds must be active to receive a notification

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385886&type=1

Answer (score 1):

As the error is saying **the recipient is not an active user**, to solve this you can:

Make sure in your flow you get only the Active users to be included as the recipient.

Get Users where isActive = true. (to get all the active users)

Alternatively, if you already know the UserId, then you should check if the user is active or not, if they are **not** active then **do not add** them to the list (collection).